# Substitute array to jsonnet

Tags: arrays, kubernetes, jsonnet

I have a jsonnet file

```
local version = std.extVar('version');
local entities = std.extVar('entities');

{

    appname::'app-dev',
    version::version,
    entities::entities,

}
```

The version field seems to be a string, but "entities" field is an array that is located near jsonnet file.
I am using `kubecfg show` to create json file and substitute variables like this:

```
kubecfg show test.jsonnet --ext-str "version=$VERSION" --ext-str "entities=$(cat entities.txt)"
```

Of course, during this command I receive an error:

```
got "string", expected "array";
```

Is there any way to substitute array using `kubecfg show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found.

kubecfg 0.15.3 has a flag that provides the way to inject jsonnet from the command line, file or environment.

```
--ext-code      | jsonnet      | commandline    | std.extVar(...) | 
--ext-code-env  | jsonnet      | environment    | std.extVar(...) |
--ext-code-file | jsonnet      | file           | std.extVar(...) |
```

So, as a result, the solution looks like that:

```
kubecfg show test.jsonnet --ext-str "version=$VERSION" --ext-code "entities=$(cat entities.txt)"
```